# Существует ли ограничение на количество вложенных ViewGroup?

Tags: android

Использую ListViewActivity и в качестве ListItem применяю следующую разметку

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cards_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#6f644d"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#228B22"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tw_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

</LinearLayout>

В моём случае, мне принципиально именно такое расположение элементов. И этот способ единственный, которым я смог разместить все как мне требуется.

Список формируется динамически, и таких элементов может быть очень много.

Существует ли какое либо ограничение на количество ViewGroup ? (Где то на англоязычном форуме попадалось, что ограничение какое то есть)
И если оно есть, какие могут быть последствия?

Если последствия всетаки есть, помогите собрать такой же вид, используя меньшее количество ViewGroup

Comment: а пробные запуски показали что-то плохое?

Comment: В принципе нет. Но это было 6 элементов списка.
По выбору элемента, переходил на следующее Activity, (при этом не закрываю предыдущее) и там при использовании цикла, получал StackOverFlowError. Конкретно с этой ошибкой разобрался. И как раз во время поиска причин ошибки, и попалось упоминание об ограничении.

Comment: Мн еще интересно, насколько правильно, использовать подобную разметку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственным ограничением на вложенность `ViewGroup` может быть только переполнение стека выделенного под разворачивание вьюшек в UI потоке. По-моему величина стека там что-то около 8 кб. Какие-то гуру говорили, что при величине вложенности порядка 15 начинаются проблемы.

Стандартным способом "убирания" вложенности вьюшек является использование `RelativeLayout` - советую присмотреться к этому способу.